# Biot-Savart-like integral for a toroidal helix

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, integration, physics, curves, divergent-integrals

The following problem originates from Physics, so I apologize if I will not use a rigorous mathematical jargon.

Let us consider a toroidal helix parametrized as follows:
$$
x=(R+r\cos(n\phi))\cos(\phi)
$$
$$
y=(R+r\cos(n\phi))\sin(\phi)
$$
$$
z=r\sin(n\phi)
$$
where $\phi\in[0,2\pi)$. The helix is flown by an electrical current, hence, according to the Biot-Savart law, a magnetic field $\pmb{B}$ is generated.

I need to compute the magnetic field at a specific point $\pmb{r}$ *belonging to the helix itself*. Of course, to cure the unwanted divergence, the integral must be regularized in such a way to exclude a little helical segment centered around $\pmb{r}$.

The position $\pmb{r}=(x_r,y_r,z_r)$ can be parametrized as follows:
$$
x_r=(R+\epsilon\cos(n\phi_1))\cos(\phi_1)
$$
$$
y_r=(R+\epsilon\cos(n\phi_1))\sin(\phi_1)
$$
$$
z_r=\epsilon\sin(n\phi_1)
$$
Similarly, the position $\pmb{s}=(x_s,y_s,z_s)$ can be parametrized as follows:
$$
x_s=(R+\epsilon\cos(n\phi_2))\cos(\phi_2)
$$
$$
y_s=(R+\epsilon\cos(n\phi_2))\sin(\phi_2)
$$
$$
z_s=\epsilon\sin(n\phi_2)
$$

The integral to be solved is:
$$
  \pmb{B}(\pmb{r})=\int^* \frac{(\pmb{s}-\pmb{r})\times\mathrm{d}\pmb{s}}{|\pmb{s}-\pmb{r}|^3} 
$$
where the symbol "*" means that the integration with respect to $\mathrm{d}\phi_2$ must be split into two intervals: $[0,\phi_1-a]$ and $[\phi_1+a,2\pi]$.

The integrand should be Taylor-expanded so to keep terms up to $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^1)$ for $\epsilon\to 0^+$. Similarly, the result of the integral should be Taylor-expanded so to keep terms up to $\mathcal{O}(a^1)$ for $a\to 0^+$.

Is the solution of this integral known? I was not able to compute it.